# Global keyboard input listener on Android

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible to intercept keyboard input on a global level on Android. For example a user types in text into an edittext (does not matter which application) I would like to access said text to check for certain words. Is this even possible with Android's security model (yes I am aware this kind of feature could be used for various wrong things too).

Thanks,
b3n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Thst's a security hole. You're welcome to modify the android firmware though

Comment: ah ok, that's what I thought. Thanks for confirming this.